# Chat notification with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm creating a Chat app. I'm using firebase, i succeed to send push notification from Firebase interface. But now i want to send notification when a user A send message to the user B as a normal chat app. I search on web and i found few things, by using **local notification**. If you have some tips that's would be awsome

I Started the implementation of the notification:

```
let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    let notificationSetting = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSetting)
```

Thanks all :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you'd need to do is have a separate [app server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#role) process monitoring your real-time database. When it notices that a chat section has been updated, it can then [send off](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) a notification through Firebase Cloud Messaging to the target user.

If you were hoping for an out-of-the-box client solution that didn't involve running your own server, that's current not an option, unfortunately.